# Is "Human" in "No Longer Human" a noun or an adjective?

Tags: adjectives, nouns

My friend and I got into a discussion whether the word "Human" in the title of the 1948 book "No Longer Human" by Osamu Dazai is a noun or an adjective. I think it is an adjective and my friend thinks it is a noun because it is a noun in the original Japanese title. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A noun would ordinarily warrant an indefinite article. I would also say it's an adjective.

Comment: "No longer human" could mean there is no person who is taller. It all depends on context.

Comment: May I ask: Why does it matter?

Comment: It's an adjective in the English title *no longer human*. 人間失格 translates as *human disqualification*. In that translation, *human* is an attributive noun, which functions like an adjective (cf. *duck* in *duck soup*). But I don't know how it works in Japanese.

Comment: "tinfoil hat But some translations are not word-for-word. [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/human) clearly indicate that they consider 'human' to have at least reconverted to adjective (how it entered the lexicon according to [Etymon](https://www.etymonline.com/word/human) in say 'It's very human to have regrets about the past.' And 'I'm only human.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Human in 'No Longer Human' is an adjective.

If it were a noun, it would take an indefinite article.

Adjective- I am only human. We are only human.

Noun- I am a human. He is a human. We are humans. They are humans.